# How do I change projectile (nail, rocket, etc) speed?

Tags: quake

I'm playing **Quake 1** in single-player mode with **QuakeSpasm 0.85.7** engine.

I want to limit the speed of projectiles, like thrown grenade, launched rocket of rocket launcher and fired nail of nailgun/supernailgun, or any other custom projectile of custom weapons.

I tried changing `sv_maxvelocity <#>`, but it overrides `sv_maxspeed <#>` and so affects the speed of my character when I set small values to it. Also, the projectiles spread to sides too much for small speed values.

Is it possible to limit the projectile speed without also limiting the player speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible with the standard commands available in the game. According to [this list of Quake console commands](http://www.onlinegamecommands.com/quake/quakeclientcommands.htm) the only two commands that effect velocity are the two that you've already mentioned; `sv_maxvelocity` and `sv_maxspeed`.

As discussed in [this forum thread on inside3d](http://forums.inside3d.com/viewtopic.php?t=2428) it is possible to change the individual velocities of the nail gun/rocket launcher/etc by using QuakeC and making amendments to the code for the weapons firing.